# Convert a abr file to a png file on a Mac

Tags: png, file-conversion

I want to take an abr file and convert it to a png file on a Mac.

I am looking for a visual reference for each .abr file I have created. I am on a mac, so ABRViewer is not available to me. But what abrviewer does is exactly what I'm looking for. BrushView QuickLook used to work in Photoshop but is not compatible with Catalina.

Comment: If you don't know how to read and parse binary files, your best bet is to find  someone with Windows and ask them to use abrviewer

Answer (score 1):

An `.abr` file is **not** an image file.

It's a brush definition file for Photoshop.

[**This article**](https://www.lifewire.com/use-photoshop-brushes-in-other-software-1701560) explains how to use Photoshop to export thumbnail images of the brush definitions. But without Photoshop, there's not much you can do with the file.

If you are seeking merely to *preview* the brush tips in the .abr file.. there are many small freeware or shareware applications to do that for Windows or The MacOS. A simply internet search for "abr viewer [insert OS]" will turn them up.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to make small thumbnail samples as a visual reference for what each brush does. I think this may be actually more useful than just extracting the brush images anyway, since a brush is often more than just an image.

In Photoshop, maybe set up a grid, choose black as the foreground colour, select each brush in turn and paint a little sample in each cell.  Use the slice tool to slice them up if you need individual PNGs, then export the slices.